# how do I get Terminal's Search with Google to open in the default browser?

Tags: macos, terminal

Scenario: working away in Terminal, get an error message. Want to google it so I select text and use right-click and "Search with Google". Opens Safari every time. Google Chrome is my default browser. I've restarted the machine twice since I confirmed that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Search with Google* is a *service* provided by Safari and has nothing to do with Terminal.

Google Chrome should provide its own service for this feature. It doesn't.

---

Or you can write your own, e.g. using Automator and AppleScript:

Open *Automator* and select to create a new *Service*. At the top, select *text* and *any application*. Then, add a *Run Shell Script* action from the library to the workflow by drag&drop or double-clicking. Change its input to *as arguments*, and paste the following script in its main text area:

```
#!/bin/bash
function urlencode {
    echo -n "$@" | perl -MURI::Escape -ne 'print uri_escape($_)'
}
open "http://google.com/search?q=$( urlencode "$@" )"
```

[image: Automator screenshot]

This will open the URL `http://google.com/search?q=` followed by your URL-escaped text selection in your default browser.

Save as *Search with Google in Default Browser* and try again.

Comment: 1. How do i get this service to appear in the main contextual menu, like Safari's does?

Comment: 2. How can I get rid of Safari's service in the contextual menu?

Comment: @aaronbauman Disable it in System Preferences » Keyboard » Shortcuts » Services. This will remove it also from the Services submenu in the application menu though, and disables its keyboard shortcut, if set.

Comment: Safari is just a browser—it may be provided *with* Safari, but it is provided *by* Apple, and Apple has no business pulling stupid shenanigans like this.  The OS needs to honor the user's choice of default browser, and so do other utilities (including Services) that Apple provides.  Please complain to Apple at http://www.apple.com/feedback/ and tell them this is absolutely unacceptable.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! `perl -MURI::Escape` didn't work out of the box, so I used that instead: `open "http://google.com/search?q=$( python -c 'from urllib import quote; print quote(raw_input(), safe="")' <<< "$*" )"`

Comment: It's important to set "Pass input:" to "as arguments" for the action in Automator (the default was "to stdin" in my case).