# Bug: System Services Remain In Context Menu, Despite Being Disabled

Tags: macos, bug, services, shortcut-menu

I have found that if one disables the built-in **"Search With Google"** and **"Look Up in Dictionary"** systemwide "Searching" Services, they are not actually disabled.

In this post, I focus on the "Search With Google" Service in particular (as it is more problematic for me; I explain why in a moment), but the "Look Up in Dictionary" Service misbehaves in exactly the same way.

---

The "Search With Google" system-wide "Searching" Service, enabled on Macs by default, opens up a Google search containing the selected text in a new tab in Safari. While the search engine can be changed, [the browser cannot be changed in this Service](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75524/how-do-i-get-terminals-search-with-google-to-open-in-the-default-browser/75531#75531).

However, my web browser of choice is Google Chrome.

I would like to disable this Service because I have recreated an identical version using Automator and AppleScript (so that I can implement the search in a new Chrome tab, instead of Safari). I am having trouble disabling this Service.

As you can see, the "Search With Google" Service and "Look Up in Dictionary" Service are unselected in System Preferences:

[image: System Preferences]

Yet, these two Services reliably pop up in my context menu:

[image: Context Menu]

I've tried restarting my computer and resetting the PRAM and SMC.

Following the instruction of [this Stack Exchange answer](https://superuser.com/a/1110607), I've tried creating a custom Service with the same title as the built-in Service, hoping that my Service would "overrule" the original. But, alas, this did not work; my custom Service shows up as a "Text" Service, not in the "Searching" category. They have identical titles, but they coexist.

By the way, I noticed this problem as soon as I started paying attention, around 1 year ago.

It may be worth noting that if (and only if) I am in Chrome.app, the "Search With Google" Service does in fact disappear ("Look Up" still appears, though). But, I think that the reason for this is because Chrome, by default, inserts *Search Google for "selected text"* into the context menu when one is in Chrome; I am guessing that Chrome has some mechanism of automatically disabling the Safari Service, irrespective of the setting in System Preferences.

Is there a way to do so system-wide, maybe via Terminal?

Do you experience the bug on your Mac? I could not find even one account of this bug online.

<sub>OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.6.</sub>

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow: How to force Mac OS to open “Search with Google” in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935301/how-to-force-mac-os-to-open-search-with-google-in-chrome), [Super User: Mac OS X (Lion) Chrome: shortcut for “Search With Google”](http://superuser.com/questions/369934/mac-os-x-lion-chrome-shortcut-for-search-with-google)

Comment: I get the same results as you do.

Comment: It's weird there are few reports of this. But can confirm this behavior on Big Sur